# Android ViewPager Indicator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hi Have a a VewPager indicator that will show what Fragment I am currently Viewing. I need to add a button under the circles but when I do i don't see any button at all.

My xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        <com.kassisdion.library.ViewPagerWithIndicator
            app:arrow.enable="true"
            app:arrow.width="10dip"
            app:arrow.height="500dip"
            app:round.enable="true"
            app:round.size="15dip"
            app:round.drawable="@drawable/background_rounded"
            app:round.color.default="@android:color/white"
            app:round.color.selected="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerWithIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.kassisdion.library.ViewPagerWithIndicator>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried changing the Layout but that just threw exceptions. 
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: you are using third party library which have already indicator layout in it . my suggestion is do layout  custom layout withs indicator will help you!

Comment: What do you mean by "button under the circles"? Where did you add the button and what exception did you get? What will be the purpose of the button?

Comment: I mean that I want to add a button under the Indicator that will allow me skip to the next fragment. 
I added it directly below the indicator section in my xml. 
There was only an exception when i changed my layout

Comment: replace the android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="0dp" and set weight   android:layout_weight="1". Set for both view pager

Comment: @kalpanac for Which items?

Comment: paste correct xml file here. where is your button?

Comment: I have updated the above XML file